# Where to find 5.x Testng eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, testng

Anyone knows where I can find TestNG eclipse plugin 5.x (5.14 for example)? the update site
http://beust.com/eclipse only lists 6.x which is causing problems for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://beust.com/eclipse-old/

cheers

Comment: Yes, that's where I put all the old versions. I'd be interested to know what problems you're having with the 6.0 plug-in, though. Feel free to email me.